# Is it possible to replace only in a match group - REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I have always tried to avoid `regex` because I simply can't get my head around how it really works. Most of the time I manage to get the expected result *by luck* more than *actual skill*.

However, I am trying to replace **any whitespace character** in a bundled webpack source with the `string-replace-loader` or the `String-Replace-Plugin` *(which ever turns out easier)*. But before I try to do this on the actual source, I want to understand the regex which I am trying to perform.

##### The problem

I have query strings which always start with `dqlParse` followed by `\n` then maybe some `\t` and other whitespace characters. I have already managed to get my whitespace characters removed in a test string if I match this

```
/\s+\s/g
```

and simply replace it with `" "`.

Since I don't have control over all the strings within my bundle, I thought I can **indicate** which string is set for replacement by adding `dqlParse` infront of the string and then **match and replace by groups**. Unfortunately no luck so far.

##### What I have tried

So far I have tried something like this

```
/(^dqlParse)(.*)/g
```

which basically does what it should since match group `$1` is `dqlParse` and match group `$2` is the rest of the string where I would like to do the replacement.

Is it possible to replace only in the second match group?

Thanks! Any help appreciated!

Comment: It really depends on what you are using. A regular expression can only match; replacement mechanisms have to be provided by the language or tool you are using. Please review the tag guidance for the [tag:regex] tag and [edit] to update your question with these details.

Comment: I have stated that I want to use it with either the `string-replace-loader` or the `String-Replace-Plugin` - so it's all **Javascript**.

Comment: That's not obvious to those of us who do not use those technologies. But thanks for following up; I have added the [tag:javascript] tag

Comment: Sorry! Was assuming that mentioning webpack is sufficient  Thanks for adding the appropriate tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with `String#replace`:

```js
text = text.replace(/^(dqlParse)(.*)/g, function(_, x, y) {return x + y.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');})
```

This will match and capture `dqlParse` into Group 1 (`x` variable in the callback function), and the rest of the line will get captured into Group 2 (`y` in the callback function). So, once the match is found, the replacement will be the concatenation of `x` and `y` with all two or more whitespace chunks replaced with a single space.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try if this is working with either one of the extensions and get back to you! 